# mysql: Running sum with reset condition from another table

Tags: mysql

i'm having a Problem where i have two Tables:

`TableHours`:

| Date | Workcenter | Available Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-14 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-09-14 | 2 | 5 |
| 2023-09-15 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-09-15 | 2 | 8 |
| 2023-09-16 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-09-17 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-09-18 | 1 | 15 |

and

`TableOrders`

| Total Execution Time | Calculated AssemblyDate | Contract_Date | Sales_Order | S_ORD_Item | ORDERID_OPER | Workcenter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10.42 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5.85 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-08 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 9.52 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-10 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 10.50 | 2023-09-10 | 2023-09-06 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 30 | 2023-09-10 | 2023-09-06 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
| 2.48 | 2023-09-12 | 2023-09-20 | 258685 | 3 | 9 | 2 |
| 1.95 | 2023-09-12 | 2023-09-21 | 25 | 6 | 20 | 1 |
| 20.10 | 2023-09-13 | 2023-09-06 | 2056 | 50 | 80 | 1 |
| 5 | 2023-09-13 | 2023-09-06 | 2056 | 51 | 80 | 1 |

The Requirement is that i should sum up the Total Execution time per Workcenter of TableOrders until the threshold of of Today's date from TableHours is reached.
Then take the next not 0 entry for the for the workorder etc.
If the available Time does not fit into the today's bucket, the next day should be Taken.

So the expected result should look like this: (Example that curday() = 2023-09-14)

| Date | Calculated Assembly Date | Contract Date | Sales Order | S_ORD_Item | ORDERID_OPER | Workcenter | Remaining Capacity Time | Remaining Processing Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-14 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2023-09-14 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 5.42 |
| 2023-09-15 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 4.58 | 0 |
| 2023-09-15 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 5.48 |
| 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 9.52 | 0 |
| 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 9.52 | 0 |
| 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-12 | 2023-09-21 | 25 | 6 | 20 | 1 | 7.75 | 0 |
| 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-13 | 2023-09-06 | 2056 | 50 | 80 | 1 | 0 | 12.35 |
| 2049-12-12 | 2023-09-13 | 2023-09-06 | 2056 | 50 | 80 | 1 | 12.35 | 0 |
| 2049-12-12 | 2023-09-13 | 2023-09-06 | 2056 | 51 | 80 | 1 | 17.35 | 0 |
| 2023-09-14 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-08 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0.85 |
| 2023-09-15 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-08 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 7.25 | 0 |
| 2023-09-15 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-10 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 2.27 |
| 2049-12-12 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-10 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 2.27 | 0 |

I tried it with the below query, but i feel like i'm missing something and that my approach is not really ideal...

```
/*
    @iCapacityDate              :   iterator for capacity date
    @iCapacity                  :   iterator for capacity value
    @capacityFlag               :   capacity condition flag
    @tempCapacity               :   temp var to retrieve next capacity when <= 0 and null, also fallback on most common
    'fix_capadate'              :   adjust from temp var capacity date
    'fix_capaval'               :   adjust from temp var capacity value
    @remainingCapacity          :   capacity remaining after current Production order
    @finalPlannedDate           :   final calculated planned production date
    @iPrevWorkcenter            :   iterator for previous workcenter value
    'reset_capa_date'           :   reset condition for capacity date iterator
    'reset_capa_rem'            :   reset condition for capacity value iterator
    'reset_workcenter_capadate' :   workcenter reset condition for capacity date iterator
    'reset_workcenter_caparem'  :   workcenter reset condition for capacity value iterator
    'reset_flag'                :   reset capacity flag
    TODO: is it easier to manage with datetime
*/
SELECT t.*,
    @iCapacityDate := IFNULL(@iCapacityDate, CURDATE()) AS 'i_Capacity_Date',
    @iCapacity := (
            SELECT a.`Available Time` FROM TableHours a
            WHERE a.Workcenter = t.Workcenter AND a.`Date` = @iCapacityDate
        ) AS 'i_Capacity',
    @capacityFlag := (@iCapacity is null or @iCapacity <= 0 
        or @iCapacity - t.`Total Execution Time` < 0 or @remainingCapacity - t.`Total Execution Time` <= 0) AS 'capacity_Flag',
    IF( @capacityFlag, @tempCapacity := IFNULL( ( /*select next day with ENOUGH capacity*/
            SELECT concat(a1.`Available Time`, '--', MIN(a1.`Date`)) FROM TableHours a1
            WHERE a1.Workcenter = t.Workcenter AND a1.`Date` > @iCapacityDate 
            AND a1.`Available Time` >= t.`Total Execution Time` ), (
                SELECT concat(a2.`Available Time`, '--', ADDDATE(@iCapacityDate, 1)) FROM TableHours a2
                WHERE a2.Workcenter = t.Workcenter GROUP BY a2.`Available Time`
                ORDER BY count(a2.`Available Time`) DESC LIMIT 1) ), '' 
        ) AS 'temp_Capacity',
    IF( @capacityFlag, @iCapacityDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@tempCapacity, '--', -1), '') AS 'fix_capadate',
    IF( @capacityFlag, @iCapacity := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@tempCapacity, '--', 1), '') AS 'fix_capaval',
    @remainingCapacity := IFNULL( @remainingCapacity - t.`Total Execution Time`, @iCapacity - t.`Total Execution Time` ) AS 'Remaining_Capacity',
    IF( @iPrevWorkcenter <> t.Workcenter, @iCapacityDate := CURDATE(), '' ) AS 'reset_workcenter_capadate',
    IF( @iPrevWorkcenter <> t.Workcenter, @remainingCapacity := (
            SELECT a.`Available Time` FROM TableHours a
            WHERE a.Workcenter = t.Workcenter AND a.`Date` = @iCapacityDate) - t.`Total Execution Time`, ''
        ) AS 'reset_workcenter_caparem',
    @finalPlannedDate := IFNULL(@iCapacityDate, CURDATE()) AS 'Final_Planned_Date',
    @iPrevWorkcenter := t.Workcenter AS 'i_Workcenter',
    @capacityFlag := false AS 'reset_flag'
FROM
    TableOrders t
ORDER BY
    t.Workcenter,
    t.CalculatedAssemblyDate,
    t.Contract_Date,
    t.ORDERID_OPER
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find the fix for it.  It's not pretty at all but gets the job done.

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    @iCapacityDate := IFNULL(@iCapacityDate, CURDATE()) AS 'i_Capacity_Date',
    @iCapacity :=
        (SELECT a.`Available Time`
         FROM   SalesCommSheetAvailableHours a
         WHERE  a.Workcenter = t.Workcenter AND a.`Date` = @iCapacityDate
        ) AS 'i_Capacity',
    @capacityFlag := (IFNULL(@iCapacity, 0) <= 0 OR IFNULL(@remainingCapacity, @iCapacity) - t.`Total Execution Time` <= 0 ) AS 'capacity_Flag',
    IF(@capacityFlag, @tempCapacity := ifnull(
        (SELECT concat(a1.`Available Time`, '--', MIN(a1.`Date`))
         FROM   SalesCommSheetAvailableHours a1
         WHERE  a1.Workcenter = t.Workcenter AND a1.`Date` > @iCapacityDate 
         AND    a1.`Available Time` >= t.`Total Execution Time`),
        (SELECT concat(a2.`Available Time`, '--', ADDDATE(@iCapacityDate, 1))
         FROM   SalesCommSheetAvailableHours a2
         WHERE  a2.Workcenter = t.Workcenter GROUP BY a2.`Available Time`
         ORDER BY count(a2.`Available Time`) DESC LIMIT 1)), '' 
        ) AS 'temp_Capacity',
    IF(@capacityFlag, @iCapacityDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@tempCapacity, '--', -1), '') AS 'fix_capadate',
    IF(@capacityFlag, @iCapacity := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@tempCapacity, '--', 1), '') AS 'fix_capaval',
    @remainingCapacity := IF(@capacityFlag, @iCapacity - t.`Total Execution Time`, ifnull(@remainingCapacity, @iCapacity) - t.`Total Execution Time` ) AS 'Remaining_Capacity',
    IF(@iPrevWorkcenter <> t.Workcenter, @iCapacityDate := CURDATE(), '' ) AS 'reset_workcenter_capadate',
    IF(@iPrevWorkcenter <> t.Workcenter, @remainingCapacity :=
        (SELECT a.`Available Time`
         FROM   SalesCommSheetAvailableHours a
         WHERE  a.Workcenter = t.Workcenter AND a.`Date` = @iCapacityDate) - t.`Total Execution Time`, ''
        ) AS 'reset_workcenter_caparem',
    @finalPlannedDate := IFNULL(@iCapacityDate, CURDATE()) AS 'Final_Planned_Date',
    @iPrevWorkcenter := t.Workcenter AS 'i_Workcenter',
    @capacityFlag := 0 AS 'reset_flag'
FROM
    IntermediateStepMySalesCommDB t
ORDER BY
    t.Workcenter,
    t.CalculatedAssemblyDate,
    t.Contract_Date,
    t.ORDERID_OPER
```